# Fallback to the external service after the n retries on pods in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio

TL;DR: How to fall back to the external service after `n` reties on cluster pods?

There is `VirtualService` that routes HTTP requests to the cluster pods and retries if pods return `503`. I need requests to be routed to the external service after the `n` retries.

Is it possible to use `x-envoy-attempt-count` header field inside `VirtualService` routing?

```
http:
  - match:
    - headers:
        x-envoy-attempt-count:
          exact: 5
```

Are there any other options?

Istio 1.9.4 It seems like during retry routes are not reevaluated so the route with the header match never gets selected.

Comment: I need something like Nginx `backup` directive for the upstream http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#upstream

Answer (score 0):

bad news...Unless smth changed currently this is not possible with Istio.
There had already been reply on this topic - maybe you missed it.

Please check
[Configure istio destination rule to use a fallback URL instead of 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65927017/configure-istio-destination-rule-to-use-a-fallback-url-instead-of-503/65937741#65937741)

> With a service mesh, at the moment without specialized libraries for
> failure context propagation, the failure reasons are more opaque. This
> doesn’t mean our application cannot take fallbacks (for both transport
> and client-specific errors). I’d argue it’s very important for the
> protocol of any application, whether using library-specific frameworks
> OR NOT) to always adhere to the promises it’s trying to keep for its
> clients. If it finds that it cannot complete its intended action, it
> should figure a way to gracefully degrade. Luckily, you don’t need
> application-specific frameworks for this. Most languages have built-in
> error and exception trapping and handling. Fallbacks should be
> implemented in these exception paths.